# Connection timed out. Why?

Tags: java

I get an exception when I run this code. Why?

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");

    URL url = new URL("https://www.verisign.com/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
    in.close();
  }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:550)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:272)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:801)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1049)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl.java:204)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at https.ssl.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:13)
```

Comment: So what steps have you previously taken to solve this yourself?

Comment: I think your connection timed out. That's what it looks like to me.

Comment: Just ping the site https://www.verisign.com/ and  see you can connect or not, or is it using much time to connect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can't diagnose your networks for you.  You need to do it yourself, or get your local admins to look at.

Things you should check **before** you bug your admins:

- can you `ping` the host?
- can you connect to `http://www.verisign.com` using a web browser?
- can you connect to `https://www.verisign.com` using a web browser?
- can you connect to `http://www.verisign.com` using your program?
- can you connect to *anything* using your program?

The chances are that your problem is firewall related.  My first guess would be that you don't have the correct environment variables or Java system properties set to tell the JVM to use a local proxy server for outgoing HTTP / HTTPS requests.

If it is not a problem with your settings, you will need to get help from someone local who can help you diagnose the problem.