# URLConnection.getInputStream() : Connection timed out

Tags: java, http, networking, timeout, connection

I use the code from [Sun's java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
        URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Stack trace is same as [Connection timed out. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907037/connection-timed-out-why)

I suspect that might be problem with firewall but

1. ping to google.com is okay
2. it works in browser
3. this approach fails for every URL I provide
4. I use DJ WebBrowser component in other program and it works okay as a browser

**How can I investigate more about this problem? 
Can I get to know which port numbers are going to be used when I run the code?**

Thanks

Comment: It is a company network. Yes, with high probability. I have not tested it anywhere else.

Comment: If you are using Firefox, go to Tools > Options > Advanced > Network > Settings and see if there is any proxy url being configured.

Comment: What about any firewall settings? What OS are you on?

Comment: In Google Chrome it says there is Automatic Configuration Script configured and not Proxy Server directly.

I am using Windows 7, there is no personal firewall, but I am sure there is company's firewall.

Comment: Are you running this code on your companies server or its just on your local machine? If its on server I think that its a firewall issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the proxy that is used by your company and set it in your program. Quoting code from [1]

```
//Set the http proxy to webcache.mydomain.com:8080

System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "webcache.mydomain.com");
System.setPropery("http.proxyPort", "8080");

// Next connection will be through proxy.
URL url = new URL("http://java.sun.com/");
InputStream in = url.openStream();

// Now, let's 'unset' the proxy.
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", null);

// From now on http connections will be done directly.
```

[1] - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Comment: that's correct! thanks. The last unset property should have "", not null.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a HttpURLConnection that might work better in some cases. It doesn't appear to disconnect in the same way.

```
URL url = new URL(address); 
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(callTimeout);
```

and so on.