# Connection timed out when accessing web service using org.apache.axis.client.Call

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis

I have used add web service client option in eclipse to create a client for a webservice (.asmx?wsdl). However, when I call the webservice through the generated client, I get a connection timeout Exception.

I have used this functionality without any issues before, and I can receive replies fine when I use soap UI to talk to the problematic webservice. I don't think wrong URL is an issue here.
Only "issue" I can see is that this webservice url is HTTPS, not HTTP. Could this cause timeout issues? (using org.apache.axis.client.Call) I am not even sure where I should start looking.

Comment: Not a simple duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907037/connection-timed-out-why as the OP has checked access by other means.