# Java RMI connection over internet

Tags: java, rmi, rmiregistry

I'm trying to get remote objects from a server hosted on different network. I'm able to connect on same machine and on same network, but when I try to get it from different network I get:

> Connection refused to host: 192.168.1.131; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

It seems that lookup function is searching at wrong network. I tried to use System.setProperty but it doesn't work. Here the code:

**Server**

```
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            System.out.println("Init server...\n");
            TestInterface test = new TestImplement();


            System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "95.247.x.x");
            System.out.println("Reg RMI...\n");
            Registry rmiRegistry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(5555);
            rmiRegistry.rebind("Test" , test);
            System.out.println("Reg completed!\n");
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}
```

**Client**

```
...
registryRMI = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("95.247.x.x",5555);
TestInterface testClient = (TestInterface)registryRMI.lookup("Test");
...
```

Do I need to set `java.rmi.server.hostname` in client jar as well?

Comment: Check if you are able to telnet on 5555 port.

Comment: as well the question is why the client tries to connect `192.168.1.131` .. maybe the registry binds the instance to that address..  did yo urestart it too?

Comment: @gusto2 'Registry binds the instance to that address' is completely meaningless. The *application* binds the *name* to the *instance* via the *Registry*. There is no notion of address in the `Registry.bind()` operation.

Comment: Not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907037/connection-timed-out-why as this is asking how to configure RIM to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
TestInterface test = new TestImplement();
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "95.247.x.x");
```

You need to set `java.rmi.server.hostname` *before* exporting any remote objects. Doing it afterwards is too late.

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "95.247.x.x");
TestInterface test = new TestImplement();
```

Comment: Ok now the client get the proper IP, but the connection is still timed out.
"Connection refused to host: 95.247.x.x; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect"
I done port forwarding in my router so it maps external  port to internal port correctly. Still getting this error.

Comment: No, you are now getting a *new* error. There is no 'still' about it. The problem is now that you haven't done the port forwarding correctly, or that 95.247.x.x is behind a firewall, or some other network connectivity problem.

Comment: The problem is not the firewall becouse if I set on server `java.rmi.server.hostname "blablabla"` on client I get `java.net.UnknownHostException: blablabla` so the client is able to retrive the registry or at least first connection, after that it can't progress for connection timed out.